# Nuclide debugging react-native application

Tags: react-native, nuclide-editor

I could not find any clear instructions on how to debug run react-native applications with nuclide.

What I did try was

1. Started a react native packager using `npm start`
2. Found the node processes running using `ps aux | grep node`.
3. Note that here that there is too many node processes here. I just attached it to `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`. Obviously this is wrong as my breakpoints are still unresolved.

So my question is which node process should I attach my debugger to.

I am pretty much giving up on Nuclide, as I think there is no real value.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this instruction](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/) you should:

1. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P) choose "Nuclide React Native: Start Packager" to start the React Native Server.
2. Ensure that you are in the root directory of the React Native project, then run the application from the command-line: "$ react-native run-ios" (or choose other existing simulator, for example react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone4s").
3. After starting the server, you can prime the React Native Debugger for when the application begins running. From the [command Palette](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/basics/#command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P), launch "Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging".
4. From the Simulator press Cmd-D (Ctrl-D on Linux). This will bring up the debug options for your application. Select "Debug JS Remotely.

...After you enable debugging from the simulated application, Nuclide will attach to that debugging process automatically, since we primed the Debugger above.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15531681)

Comment: "it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here" done